# Centos 7 - "systemctl restart nginx" return error

Tags: centos, nginx

If i run **systemctl restart nginx** i am getting following error, how to solve this?

> Error: No space left on device Job for nginx.service failed because
>   the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status
>   nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: The error is explicit: check your filesystems (`df`). One of them is full.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that you need to free up space in your system. To do this, you may want to look [run all the commands](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/clear-disk-space-centos). Primarily, you can trim excessive log files. They are typical disk space offenders on a misconfigured system, thus:

```
find /var -name "*.log" \( \( -size +50M -mtime +7 \) -o -mtime +30 \) -exec truncate {} --size 0 \;
```

> This will truncate any *.log files on the volume /var that are either older than 7 days and greater than 50M or older than 30 days.